# Is there a faster/better way to do an iterative list intersection?

Tags: python, pandas, list, performance, dataframe

I'm trying to get a list of credit for any given opportunity ('opp') exclusive to the maximal combinations of 'touches' in my test DataFrame.

So for every combination of touches, I get the intersection of all unique opps (intersect_list).
Then I remove the opp if it also exists in a superset (remove_common_elements)

I'm encountering a really long run time doing this with real data, but i can't figure out a better way to do it. The intersect_list is what takes the longest by far (several hours for ~65k entries of real data, where any given nested list has < 10 elements)

I can't figure out how to do an apply or list comprehension, etc...or other way to speed this up.

```
test = pd.DataFrame(data={'opp':['a','a','a','b','b','c','a','b','c','d'],'touch':['z','y','x','y','z','x','z','y','x','z']})

touches = test['touch'].unique().tolist()

test_array_indices = list(range(0,len(touches)))
test_array_combos = []

for i in range(1,len(touches)+1):
 test_array_combos.extend(combinations(test_array_indices,i))

def intersect_list(list1, list2):
 result = [i for i in list1 if i in list2]
 return result

def remove_common_elements(list1,list2):
 result = [i for i in list1 if i not in list2]
 return result

k = []
for i in range(0,len(touches)):
 k.append(test[test['touch'] == touches[i]]['opp'].unique().tolist())

test_opp_list = []
for j in range(0,len(test_array_combos)):
 t = []
 for i in range(0,len(test_array_combos[j])):
     t.append(k[test_array_combos[j][i]])
 test_opp_list.append(t)

list_t = []
for i in range(0,len(test_opp_list)):
 list_t.append([])
 
for i in range(0,len(test_opp_list)):
 list_t[i] = test_opp_list[i][0]
 for j in range(0,len(test_opp_list[i])):
     list_t[i] = intersect_list(list_t[i],test_opp_list[i][j])

for i in range(0,len(list_t)-1):
 for j in range(1, len(list_t)-i):
     list_t[i] = remove_common_elements(list_t[i], list_t[i+j])
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: If I run the above I get: [['d'], [], ['c'], ['b'], [], [], ['a']] which is correct:
Touch z gets d
Touch x gets c
Touch z&y gets b
Touch z&y&x gets a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing I found so far is to turn the list of lists into a list or sets. This speeds things up by about 4x for my tiny data set, but as I understand the difference grows exponentially with size.

```
test = pd.DataFrame(data={'opp':['a','a','a','b','b','c','a','b','c','d'],'touch':['z','y','x','y','z','x','z','y','x','z']})

touches = test['touch'].unique().tolist()
k = []
for i in range(0,len(touches)):
     k.append(set(test[test['touch'] == touches[i]]['opp'].unique().tolist()))

test_array_indices = list(range(0,len(touches)))
test_array_combos = []

for i in range(1,len(touches)+1):
     test_array_combos.extend(combinations(test_array_indices,i))

 test_opp_list_sets = []
 for j in range(0,len(test_array_combos)):
     t = []
     for i in range(0,len(test_array_combos[j])):
         t.append(k[test_array_combos[j][i]])
     test_opp_list_sets.append(t)

 list_s = []
 for i in range(0,len(test_opp_list_sets)):
      list_s.append([])

 for i in range(0, len(test_opp_list_sets)):
      list_s[i] = test_opp_list_sets[i][0].intersection(*test_opp_list_sets[i])

 for i in range(0,len(list_s)-1):
      for j in range(1, len(list_s)-i):
           list_s[i] = list_s[i] - list_s[i+j]
```